# Unable to load shared object in R compiled with gfortran : undefined symbol: _gfortran_st_close

Tags: r, shared-libraries, gfortran, .so

I'm using a code in R that relies on another fortran code compiled from R.

The exact same (collection of) code works fine on another laptop, so it's probably a matter of external libraries.

The error arise when attempting to load the ".so" object:

```
    dyn.load("./Build/bamhbi_interface.so")
```

which results in this error message which left me without solutions :

```
Error in dyn.load("./Build/bamhbi_interface.so") : 
  unable to load shared object './Build/bamhbi_interface.so':
  ./Build/bamhbi_interface.so: undefined symbol: _gfortran_st_close
```

**Context**

- Ubuntu 20.04
- R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
- GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
- The fortran code were compiled using

```
  system("R CMD COMPILE bamhbi_alkalinity.f90")
  system("R CMD COMPILE bamhbi_nemo2r.f90")
  [...]
  system("R CMD COMPILE bamhbi_interface.f90")

  system("R CMD SHLIB -o bamhbi_interface.so bamhbi_alkalinity.o bamhbi_nemo2r.o [...] bamhbi_diagnostics.o bamhbi_interface.o")
```

- Since I use a '~/.R/Makevars' file, the compilation command amounts to :

`gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -cpp -fdefault-real-8 -ffree-line-length-512 -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-3.6.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -c  bamhbi_nemo2r.f90 -o bamhbi_nemo2r.o`

and

`gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o bamhbi_interface.so bamhbi_alkalinity_vars.o bamhbi_alkalinity.o benthic_metamodels.o bamhbi.o bamhbi_sinking.o bamhbi_nemo2r.o bamhbi_diagnostics.o bamhbi_interface.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR` for the R CMD SHLIB step

Comment: You need `libgfortran` to be loaded as well.

Comment: Thank you @VladimirF ! This seems promising, but unfortunately not sufficient for my understanding. Would you mind give a bit more details ? Such as:  at which step this should be done, how it could be done ?

Answer (score 0):

@vladimir-f provided the answer :

Complementing the linking command with -lgfortran to load libgfortran does the trick:

```
 system("R CMD SHLIB -o bamhbi_interface.so bamhbi_alkalinity.o bamhbi_nemo2r.o [...] bamhbi_diagnostics.o bamhbi_interface.o -lgfortran")
```

Comment: I got into the same problem with undefined gfortran symbol... with install.packages(), is there a way I can add this flag in Makevars? I current have FLIBS=-L/usr/bin/gfortran and F77=/usr/bin/gfortran but did not work..